# Monic irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_3[X]$

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, irreducible-polynomials

I am trying to find monic irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_3[X]$ of degree 2 and for me it is enough to find a and b in $\mathbb{F}_3$ such that for P(X) = X²+aX+b then P(0), P(1), P(-1), P(2) and P(-2) are different from $0$. Thus I obtain the following polynomials:
$X²+1\\
X²+X-1\\
X²-X-1\\
X²+2X-1\\
X²-2X-1\\
X²-2\\
X²+X+2\\
X²-X+2\\
X²+2X+2\\
X²-2X+2$

But according to my research, I'm wondering if it's totally right... Could you help me, or tell me where my reasoning is wrong! I thank you in advance!!

Comment: Not all polynomials in the list are different since 2=-1 and 1=-2 in the coefficient field.

Comment: See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4030673/all-monic-polynomials-of-degree-2-in-bbb-f-3x-there-should-be-nine-of-th?noredirect=1&lq=1), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148368/find-the-monic-irreducible-polynomials-of-degree-2-in-f-3). There are $9$. You have $10$, so two coincide in your list.

Comment: @Wuestenfux of course !! Thank you ! I just have to do my methodology with 0, 1 and 2 !

Comment: So I obtain : $X^2+1\\
X^2+X+2\\
X^2+2X+2$ Because P(0) $\neq$ 0 then b =1 or 2 and if b = 1 then a = 0 because P(1= and P(2) are différent from 0. And if b =2 then a = 1 or 2. IS it right ?

Answer (score 0):

So I obtain : $X^2+1,X^2+X+2,X^2+2X+2$ Because P(0) ≠ 0 then b =1 or 2 and if b = 1 then a = 0 because P(1) and P(2) are différent from 0. And if b =2 then a = 1 or 2. Is it right ?

Comment: This doesn't answer your own question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, thank the previous answers I know that -1 =2 et -2 =1 so, my reasoning was wrong, so I think that the correct answer is what I wrote previously in the answer.