# Question over the splitting field of a certain polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra

I read in a resolution of an exercise that the splitting field of the polynomial $ f(x)=x^{4}+2x^{3}-1 $  over $  \Bbb Z_{3}[x]$ is obtained expanding $\Bbb Z_{3}$ with any root of the polynomial $f(x)$

could someone give me an explanation of this?

Comment: Hint: Let $x=1.$

Comment: i will get $ f(1)=2 $ so $ (x-1)$ isn't a factor of the polynomial $ f(x)$ in $\Bbb Z_{3}[x]$

Comment: I don't see a way to go further

Comment: It just means that $\alpha$ is a zero of $f$ in some extension field of ${\bf Z}_3$, then ${\bf Z}_3(\alpha)$ is the splitting field of $f$ over ${\bf Z}_3$.

Comment: what I didn't understand is why the other two roots are in $\Bbb Z_{3}(\alpha)$

Comment: Every finite extension of a finite field is a splitting field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we knew $f(x) = x^4-x^3-1$ to be irreducible, then $\Bbb F_3[x]/(f)$ would be isomorphic to $\Bbb F_{81}$, and by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148368) we would get the claim in OP. We can check irreducibility by hand, but I'd like to present another method.

I claim that if $f(\alpha) = 0$, $\alpha \in \Bbb F_3[x]/(f)$, then $\alpha$ is invertible and has multiplicative order exactly $80$. To verify this, we need to compute $x^{16}$, $x^{40}$ and $x^{80}$ modulo $f$.

$x^4=x^3+1$, $x^5=x^3+x+1$, $x^6=x^3+x^2+x+1$;

$x^8 = (x^3+1)^2 = (x^3+x^2+x+1)+2x^3+1=x^2+x+2$;

$x^{16} = (x^8)^2 = 2x^2+x+2 \not = 1$;

$x^{40} = (x^{16})^2 x^8 = (2x^3+x+2)(x^2+x+2)= 2 \not = 1$;

$x^{80}$ is then clearly $1$.

So the quotient is indeed a field of order $81$, and we additionally got a remarkable fact that $f$ is a [primitive polynomial in the sense of field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_polynomial_(field_theory)): each of its roots is a generator of the multiplicative group of the quotient field.

(Note that, in general, a root of an irreducible polynomial need not generate the whole splitting field, as e.g. $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2})$ is not the whole splitting field of $x^4-2$ over $\Bbb Q$; the first link in my post deals specifically with *finite* fields.)

Comment: how can you assert that $2x^2+x+2≠1$?

Comment: @Marco The elements of the quotient ring are the cosets of polynomials modulo the ideal $(f)$. By polynomial division, each coset contains a unique representative of degree at most $3$. The $\not =$ refers to these representatives.

Comment: all the polynomials of degree less or equal to 3 in ${\Bbb F_{3}[x]\over (f(x))}$ are not redundant.i got. thank's for the reply